# Join with order by in Entity - but need only last date for the Closed Balance

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

i am looking for help to join 3 tables but from the last table
I only need the last entry by date for the balance. I tried OrderByDescending
for the GLBalances table .

```
var list = await (from ba in _context.BankAccounts
            join bnk in _context.Banks on ba.BankId equals bnk.ID
            join glB in _context.GLBalances on ba.BankGL equals glB.GLAccountGuid
            select new BankAccountDto()
            {
                BankId = ba.BankId,
                AccountNumber = ba.AccountNumber,
                BankName = bnk.BankName,
                Notes = ba.Notes,
                Description = ba.Description,
                Balance = (decimal)glB.ClosingBalance // ***need the last entry by date

            }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: I do not see a date in your given code, but `SELECT TOP 1` ... ` ORDER BY date DESC` will give you your requested result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the last entry by date for the `GLBalances` table, you can use the `OrderByDescending` method to sort the `GLBalances` records by date in descending order. Am assuming here column name is `Date`

You can modify your query to achieve this:

```
var list = await (from ba in _context.BankAccounts
            join bnk in _context.Banks on ba.BankId equals bnk.ID
            join glB in _context.GLBalances
                .OrderByDescending(glb => glb.Date)
                .Where(glb => glb.GLAccountGuid == ba.BankGL)
                .Take(1) on ba.BankGL equals glB.GLAccountGuid
            select new BankAccountDto()
            {
                BankId = ba.BankId,
                AccountNumber = ba.AccountNumber,
                BankName = bnk.BankName,
                Notes = ba.Notes,
                Description = ba.Description,
                Balance = (decimal)glB.ClosingBalance
            }).ToListAsync();
```

Updated. try this,

```
            var list = await (from ba in _context.BankAccounts
            join bnk in _context.Banks on ba.BankId equals bnk.ID
            join glB in _context.GLBalances.OrderByDescending(glb => glb.EndDate).Take(1)
              on ba.BankGL equals glB.GLAccountGuid 
            where glB.GLAccountGuid == ba.BankGL
            select new BankAccountDto()
            {
                BankId = ba.BankId,
                AccountNumber = ba.AccountNumber,
                BankName = bnk.BankName,
                Notes = ba.Notes,
                Description = ba.Description,
                Balance = (decimal)glB.ClosingBalance
            }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: thank you for your quick response.,  getting an error the name ba does not exist in the current context in line  .Where(glb => glb.GLAccountGuid == ba.BankGl)

Comment: @user1319463 Try updated code

Comment: Super-it worked , needed to modify it little , switched left and right of equal, works great, thank you very much for your help